# Custom `ToggleStyle` not re-rendering correctly when bound to an `ObservableObject` with the `Equatable` protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios17

## Current setup:

#### Models:

###### Book.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI
final class Book: ObservableObject {
    @Published var games: [Game] = []
    
    init() {
        self.games = [Game(), Game(), Game()]
    }
}
```

###### Game.swift

```swift
final class Game: ObservableObject, Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var isSelected: Bool = false
    
    init() {}
    
    static func ==(lhs: Game, rhs: Game) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

#### Views:

###### ContentView.swift

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var book: Book = Book()

    var body: some View {
        Games(games: $book.games)
    }
}
```

###### Games.swift

```swift
struct Games: View {
    @Binding var games: [Game]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach($games) { game in
            Toggle("Game", isOn: game.isSelected)
                .toggleStyle(CustomToggleStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

#### ToggleStyle:

###### CustomToggleStyle.swift

```swift
struct CustomToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Button {
            configuration.isOn.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text(configuration.isOn ? "On" : "Off")
        }
    }
}
```

## Problem:

This setup renders 3 toggles. One for each `Game` in the `Book` object. When tapping a toggle the `book.isSelected` value correctly updates.
*(Can be verified by attaching a `didSet` block to `isSelected` in `Game`; or `games` in `Book`)*

However, the toggle style itself always renders "Off" and doesn't update its view.

## Expected behaviour:

When tapping the toggles. I expect both the `isSelected` value to toggle, and the toggle view to correctly show "on" or "off" based on `isSelected`.

## What I found out:

- When I remove the `Equatable` protocol on `Game`. It works as expected. Although I don't understand why.

```swift
final class Game: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var isSelected: Bool = false
    
    init() {}
}
```

- When I render the `ForEach` block directly inside `ContentView`. Omitting the `Games` view and its `Binding var games` property. It also works as expected. I also don't understand why.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var book: Book = Book()

    var body: some View {
        ForEach($book.games) { game in
            Toggle("Game", isOn: game.isSelected)
                .toggleStyle(CustomToggleStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

## Questions:

1. Is there something wrong with my code why the current setup doesn't work?
2. Why does removing the `Equatable` protocol from `Game` affect the toggle?
3. Why does working around the extra `View` with the `Binding` property work as expected?

## Context:

- The current setup was tested in a `playground app`.
- This code used to work on IOS 16. The issue only happens since IOS 17.

Comment: Why not bind the value you actually need bound instead of binding the object, which (at least from your demo code) never changes. I.e. have `isOn: $game.isSelected` and `ForEach(games)`. Yes, structural changes will be needed to allow that, but basically get rid of any bindings and published for things that do not change.

Answer (score 0):

```
static func ==(lhs: Game, rhs: Game) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
```

Is literally telling SwiftUI to only render when the `id` changes. You need to include all variables unless you have a really really good reason.

Also, each `ObservableObject` needs to be wrapped, make sure each `game` uses something like.

```
@ObservedObject var game: Game
```

in a subview